# Exceptions from boost::async() lose type

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-thread, stdasync

Boost version: 1.61, GCC version 6.2.0, C++14

Exceptions inside a `boost::async()` call seem to lose their type, while it works correctly with `std::async`. Is there a fundamental difference between `std::async` and `boost::async` I'm missing?

The following code works (using `std::async`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

struct MyException : std::exception {
  const char* what() const noexcept override { return "message"; }
};

int main() {
  try {
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [] { throw MyException(); });
    future.get();
  } catch (const MyException& e) {
    cout << "MyException caught. Message: " << e.what() << endl;
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    cout << "std::exception caught. Message: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
}
```

and outputs

```
$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++14 -lpthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system && ./a.out
MyException caught. Message: message
```

However, the following code (it's the same, just using `boost::async` instead of `std::async`) does not work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct MyException : std::exception {
  const char* what() const noexcept override { return "message"; }
};

int main() {
  try {
    auto future = boost::async(boost::launch::async, [] { throw MyException(); });
    future.get();
  } catch (const MyException& e) {
    cout << "MyException caught. Message: " << e.what() << endl;
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    cout << "std::exception caught. Message: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
}
```

It outputs:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++14 -lpthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system && ./a.out
std::exception caught. Message: std::exception
```

It also doesn't work for `boost::future::then` continuations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct MyException : std::exception {
  const char* what() const noexcept override { return "message"; }
};

int main() {
  try {
    auto future = boost::make_ready_future(3).then([](boost::future<int>) -> int { throw MyException(); });
    future.get();
  } catch (const MyException& e) {
    cout << "MyException caught. Message: " << e.what() << endl;
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    cout << "std::exception caught. Message: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
}
```

outputs:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++14 -lpthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system && ./a.out
std::exception caught. Message: std::exception
```

So the concrete type of the exception seems to be lost when crossing the thread boundary. However, it doesn't seem to be connected to threading, because according to my tests, the same is true for `std::launch::deferred` (which works fine) and `boost::launch::deferred` (which loses the exception type).

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Any workaround?